# NGINX redirect 404 errors to an external URL

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

I haven't found any way to configure 404 errors to redirect to an external URL like http://google.com.

I have found ways to redirect to another page like /404.html, but not an external URL.

For instance, I would like to redirect any 403 or 404 errors to http://google.com.  Is this possible?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your server http { ... } block in nginx.conf you can add:

```
error_page 404 /example.com.404.html;

location = /example.com.404.html {
  root    html;
  allow   all;
  index   example.com.404.html
  rewrite ^ $scheme://www.someothersite.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```

Comment: i have added this block directly in my server block but apparently there is no redirection, can you explain me how it works plz, this may work ?

 error_page 404 /40x.html;

         location = /40x.html {
                root   html;
                rewrite ^(.*) http://www.google.com permanent;
}

Comment: You should include your domain on the error page's path, so you now have a location block for your website, then a separate location for each 40x error type you wish to redirect.

Comment: The actual path should be different. I could have /home/richard/public_html as root for my website and /home/richard/public_html/errors for 40x's. Specify the error page html as the index page to redirect from within the new location block.

Answer (score 0):

Add redirect javascript code to your 404.html page so that whenever your error page loads it redirects to the mentioned target website.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
top.location.href = 'http://www.your_target_site.com';
```

Comment: I have a meta redirection in 404.html but it s very slow to do redirection, i think there is a mean to do this redirection in the nginx.conf

Answer (score 0):

```
error_page 404 = @redirect;

location @redirect {
  return 301 https://yoururl.com;
}
```